# Is there a way in Javascript to read either a Byte, String or Short from a data file?

Tags: javascript

I am converting some old Code and want to try and replicate loading data files using Bytes, Shorts and Strings as the data for various things.

```
WriteString(levfile,levdesigner$(l))
WriteString(levfile,levcreation$(l))
WriteString(levfile,levlastsave$(l))
WriteByte(levfile,levprotect(l))
WriteString(levfile,levnam$(l))
WriteByte(levfile,levdim(l,0))
WriteByte(levfile,levdim(l,1))
For y=0 To levdim(l,1)-1
    For x=0 To levdim(l,0)-1
        WriteShort(levfile,map(l,x,y))
    Next
Next
```

levfile is the name of the data file

Above is the old code i used to write the data file, is there anything equivalent in javascript?

So if i store a TEXT file on ther server with this saved structure, can you read it from the file on the server?

Comment: By "javascript" do you mean node.js or the browser?

Comment: so at the moment i am looking for a way to read some text data file on the server to load in level data e.g. tile map data? Is there recemmended way to save files so they are readable on the server from javascript.